# How does spring handle exceptions in MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Spring MVC exception handle

In my opinion there are different kinds of exceptions in a Spring MVC application.

For example, the service or dao layer may throw exceptions once errors occured. Or the spring itself may throw exceptions if it can not find a right handler to handle the request.

And now I try to use the `ControllerAdvice` to handle the exceptions:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GlobalExceptionHandler.class);

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public ModelAndView myError(Exception exception) {
        log.error(exception.getMessage());
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        mav.addObject("exception", exception);
        mav.setViewName("error");
        return mav;
    }
}
```

However once I visit a wrong page, I will get the 404 error page from tomcat, rather than the `error` view defined in the `ControllerAdvice`.

So how did spring handle the exceptions?

Answer (score 0):

I Think you rather put the error page in Web.xml, whenever you will visit the wrong page it will be redirected to this error page. Also this is less cumbersome and easy to manage.

Does this answers your question